# XPath (XSLT) computing a different date from given date

Tags: date, xslt, xpath, data-conversion

I'm trying to calculate maturity date of a term loan using information from the application. I know the functions to brake down a given date mm/dd/yyyy into date, month and year. Is there a function to create the new date after i've changed these values. 
for example - a 360 month term loan with first payment date on 1/17/2016 will expire on 12/17/2045. 
Please help! 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

If your XSLT processor includes, or can load a version of, the EXSLT extension libraries, those can provide date manipulation functions (http://exslt.org/date/).

If you are using XSLT 2.0, date functions are included.

If neither of these is available, you get to implement it yourself, possibly by using custom extension functions that call Java date methods.